# how to append multiple elements to a new list by filter an old one

Tags: python

I have a list like `[ ((xs,xe),idx),...]`

I want to collect xs and xe into a set,like this way

```
s={ xs,xe for ((xs,xe),idx)
```

I know I can use it two times and add xs,xe respectively.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Isn't that just `{ x for x,y in a }` ?

Comment: more probably  `{x for xx,idx in my_list for x in xx}` not sure if 'better' than doing it in 2 times though...

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish or how the code in your question—which doesn't do any filtering and isn't even valid Python syntax—is supposed to work. Please [edit] your question and at least show a more complete example of the input and desired output (because maybe we can then figure-out what you want to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [((1,2), 'a'), ((3,4), 'b')]
>>> s = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(pair for pair, _ in lst))
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks complex, May be I rather use two times s={a for (a,b),idx in lst }|{b for (a,b),idx in lst }

Comment: The only real complexity is the length of the name of the class method involved. `fi = itertools.chain.from_iterable; s = set(fi(pair for pair, _ in lst))`. There's no reason to iterate over your set twice, building two separate temporary `set` objects that need to be merged into a third object.

Comment: It might help to start with `chain` itself, which just takes multiple arguments. `chain(a, b, c)` (if the arguments are lists) is roughly the same as `a + b + c`. If you already have `lst = [a, b, c]`, you can use `chain(*lst)`, or `chain.from_iterable(lst)`.